# IIS7 URL rewrite

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I had urls like this:

`http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=someString&product_id=1111111`

and I need to redirect al requests coming to index.php to this:

`http://www.domain.com/p/1111111/`

I am aware of apache's methodology via .htaccess, but how do I do it on IIS7 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the IIS 7 [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) module.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rule (I'm assuming it's an inbound rule):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SFRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="index\.php" />
      <action type="Redirect" 
              url="/p/{C:3}" 
              appendQueryString="false" 
              redirectType="Found" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" 
             pattern="route=([_0-9a-z-\/]+)(?:&amp;|&amp;amp;)path=([A-Za-z]+)(?:&amp;|&amp;amp;)product_id=([0-9]+)" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```